# RadioButton to TextArea Issue

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, textarea

I can not get the text from a radio button to show when selected into a text area.  can only get a true or false value. The code below is where I am having the issue. I would appreciate any advice.

```
 jTextArea2.setText(String.valueOf("Mixed Flavors:" + jRadioButton1.isSelected() + jRadioButton2.isSelected()
          + jRadioButton3.isSelected() + jRadioButton4.isSelected()));
```

Comment: you are not at all trying to get radiobutton text, you just trying for whether it is selected or not. So what else you expect from java?

Comment: Welcome to StakcOverflow.  @jackjay has a good point - you're object methods are likely only returning true or false.  A good start is to include any errors you see and document what else you may have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get text You have to use `getText()` on your radiobutton. Also there is no need of using `String.valueOf()` as the whole thing which you are trying to set in TextArea will became a String.

```
 jTextArea2.setText("Mixed Flavors:" + jRadioButton1.getText() + ":" + 
       jRadioButton1.isSelected() + " , "  + jRadioButton2.getText() + ":" +
       jRadioButton2.isSelected() + " , "+ jRadioButton3.getText() + ":"  + 
       jRadioButton3.isSelected() + " , " + jRadioButton4.getText() + ":" + 
       jRadioButton4.isSelected());
```

Comment: Thank  you for posting explanation with your solution and not just code (1+)

Answer (score 1):

**I can not get the text from a radio button to show when selected into a text area**, I just hope that means you want to try something like

```
if( jRadioButton1.isSelected() )
    jTextArea2.setText( String.valueOf("BLA") + jRadioButton1.getText() );
if( jRadioButton2.isSelected() )
    jTextArea2.setText( String.valueOf("BLA") + jRadioButton2.getText() );
if( jRadioButton3.isSelected() )
    jTextArea2.setText( String.valueOf("BLA") + jRadioButton3.getText() );
if( jRadioButton4.isSelected() )
    jTextArea2.setText( String.valueOf("BLA") + jRadioButton4.getText() );
```